# Unmerge branch merge

Tags: git

So I have a `develop` branch that I made updates on and then switched over to my `master` branch and did a `git merge develop` that brought over the updates.

Is there a way that I can unmerge those items in `master`? I didn't commit anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be clear, you ran, as the last two commands:

```
git checkout master
git merge develop
```

If `git merge` *finished*, one of these things happened:

- it did nothing (after saying "already up to date"); or
- it did a fast-forward; or
- it made a commit on its own.

In the first case, there is nothing you need to do.

In the second case, you will have seen a message along these lines:

> ```
> Updating cef09e1..3b11407
> Fast-forward
>  [more git messages here]
> ```

To undo this, assuming you have done *no other Git commands at all* since then, you can run `git reset --hard @{1}`.  If you have done some other commands, you might need to find the right hash ID for your `git reset` command.

In the third case, Git printed a lot of stuff, demanded a *log message* in which you explain the *reason* for adding this new merge commit, and then made a new merge commit.  You can remove this merge commit from your current `master` branch using `git reset --hard @{1}`, exactly as before; if you have done other Git things, you have to find the right hash ID as before, but it is *likely* to be available using the name `HEAD~1` as well.

If the merge *did not finish*, but instead told you about some conflicts that you need to resolve, you can undo the incomplete merge using `git merge --abort`.

Comment: Thanks so much @torek, apologies for the late follow up! Would you be able to upvote my question if it made sense :)